# No result when executing multiple statements with PHP ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a problem with executing multiple queries at once with ODBC in PHP.

My code:

```
$createRowQ = "
    declare @myid uniqueidentifier; 
    set @myid = NEWID(); 
    insert into tps_attachment_data values (@myid, ''); 
    print @myid;
";
$createRow = odbc_prepare($connection, $createRowQ);
odbc_execute($createRow);
$result = odbc_result_all($createRow);
```

Result:

Variable `$result` is empty and PHP is giving me this warning with SQL error:

> PHP Warning:  odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]46023075-414D-4FF2-87D5-B3B462FE3AF8, SQL
>   state 01000 in SQLExecute in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\receiver.php on line
>   656

I think that the problem is in calling multiple statements at once, but I need to declare my ID to be able to print it. Any help would be appreciated.

SQL statement works just fine when I execute it in Management Studio.

PHP version is 7.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce this warning, so the following answer provides a possible solution for this issue. The necessary changes are:

- Use `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your statement to prevent SQL Server from passing the count of rows affected as part of the result set.
- Use `SELECT @myid AS MyID` instead of `PRINT @myid` to return the generated unique identifier as a result set.
- Use `odbc_exec()` to prepare and execute an SQL statement.

PHP:

```
<?php

...
$createRowQ = "
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier;
    SET @myid = NEWID();
    INSERT INTO tps_attachment_data VALUES (@myid, ''); 
    SELECT @myid AS MyID;
    --PRINT @myid
";

$result = odbc_exec($connection, $createRowQ);
$line = odbc_fetch_array($result);
echo $line["MyID"];
...

?>
```